# How do you get a Twilio TwiML Bin to call forward with a whisper, redirect to studio on no answer and also hangup on my hangup

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

When I hangup on my end it still goes to studio flow (voicemail) through return for the other person. I want it to hangup on a hangup. I want when someone doesn't answer it goes to my studio flow voicemail record.

[MAIN TWILM BIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AB7k.png)

[STUDIO FLOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF1YW.png)

If I set a timeout in studio flow side it either gives and error or doesn't do anything when I tried.

Answer (score 0):

In the first screenshot, you have the [Action](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#action) url set for the Dial verb. After you hang-up, Twilio uses the Action url to determine what to do next. If you want to hang-up then either remove the url or make sure the url endpoint returns a hang-up based on the call status that Twilio will send to that endpoint.

> The action attribute accepts a URL as its argument. This URL tells
> Twilio where to make a POST or GET request after the dialed call ends.

Twilio's blog has a helpful example, ["How to Handle No-Answer/Pickup Scenario with Voicemail](https://www.twilio.com/blog/handle-no-answer-scenarios-voicemail-callback)" for how to setup a voicemail. It shows how the Action endpoint will receive a property that the call has hung-up.

Also, what you are trying to do, redirecting to a Studio Flow may not be possible. I haven't tried this recently, but when I did, it did not work...You cannot redirect an in-progress call into Twilio Studio. This stack overflow post covers a similar situation "[Twilio - Update call in function to studio flow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73299048/twilio-update-call-in-function-to-studio-flow)". Maybe it works now but the documentation implies that a redirect is not a valid way to [trigger the start of a Flow](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/trigger-start):

> The Trigger (Start) Widget begins each unique Studio Flow, and allows
> your Flow to respond to an incoming message, call, or a Flow initiated
> with the Studio REST API. You cannot delete this Widget from your
> Flow.